# binaryTree recursion loop returns None

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have this function called `print_tree_array` that is supposed to print out an array of a binary tree from left to right, like this: `[460, 517, 72, 33, 699, 789, 764, 685, 961, 851]`.  it does that fine, until the last loop. Then it just returns a `None` even tho i do `return array` on the `else` statement

I have tried many thing and have concluded that the binary tree works and the "framework" is set up correctly.

```py
class node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value= value
        self.r_child=None
        self.l_child=None

class tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None

    def insert(self, value, cur_node):
        if(self.root==None):
            self.root=node(value)
        else:
            if(value<cur_node.value):
                if(cur_node.l_child==None):
                    cur_node.l_child=node(value)
                else:
                    self.insert(value, cur_node.l_child)    
            elif(value>cur_node.value):
                if(cur_node.r_child==None):
                    cur_node.r_child=node(value)
                else:   
                    self.insert(value, cur_node.r_child)    

    def print_tree_array(self, cur_node, array=[]):
        if(self.root==None):
            return []
        else:
            if(cur_node!=None):
                self.print_tree_array(cur_node.l_child, array)
                self.print_tree_array(cur_node.r_child, array)
                print(array)
                return array.append(cur_node.value)
            else:
                return array        

    def get_root(self):
        return self.root 


def fill_with_random(tree, size, min_range, max_range):
    from random import randint
    for _ in range(size):
        value = randint(min_range, max_range)
        print(value)
        tree.insert(value, tree.root)
    return tree

current_tree = tree()
current_tree = fill_with_random(tree=current_tree, size=10, min_range=0, max_range=999)
print(current_tree.print_tree_array(cur_node=current_tree.root))
```

```
708
999
534
79
692
39
904
979
46
568
[]
[46]
[46, 39]
[46, 39, 79]
[46, 39, 79, 568]
[46, 39, 79, 568, 692]
[46, 39, 79, 568, 692, 534]
[46, 39, 79, 568, 692, 534, 979]
[46, 39, 79, 568, 692, 534, 979, 904]
[46, 39, 79, 568, 692, 534, 979, 904, 999]
None
```

That is what it prints out, as you can see it fills up the binary tree using the first printed lines. Then it goes on to beautifully append every "end" of the tree to the array. But it fails to append the right most item and return the whole array.

Comment: `return array.append(cur_node.value)` returns `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array.append actually doesn't return anything but it only appends to the original list

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append

If you want you should return array after appending.

Comment: Yep, I did! I'm pretty knew to StackOverflow so I didn't know